# node.js cannot get user principal from Spring Boot Security

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

Spring Security is protecting two separate Spring Boot backend services that are running on two separate ports from two separate jar files.  One of the services (called [`resource`, with full code at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/resource/src/main/java/demo/ResourceApplication.java)) responds to GET requests from a frontend Node.js server, but the other service (called [`authserver`, will full code at this link.](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java)) does not.  **How can I alter spring security settings so that the `authserver` app can respond to requests from the node.js server?**

Here is the express.js code from the node.js server which makes the requests to the two backend services:

```
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    // application --------------------------------
    app.get('/resource/**', function(req, res) {
        request.get('http://localhost:9000/resource', function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){console.log('ERROR with resource request.')}
            if (!error){// && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                console.log(body);
            };
        });
        console.log("You Hit The Resource Route ");
    });

    app.get('/user/**', function(req, res) {
        request.get('http://localhost:9999/uaa/user', function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){console.log('ERROR with user request.')}
            if (!error){// && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                console.log(body);
            };
        });
        console.log("You Hit The User Route ");
    });

};
```

And here are the `nodemon` logs showing that:
1.) the call to the `authserver` app's `/uaa/user` endpoint gave a `304` response (the Spring Boot `authserver` app's logs do NOT show any evidence of receiving the request), and
2.) that the `resource` app's `/resource` endpoint returned a `401` response (the Spring Boot `resource` app logs DO show that it received the request):

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
App listening on port 8080
GET /user 304 4.257 ms - -
You Hit The Resource Route 
401
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I confirmed that typing `http://localhost:9999/uaa/user` into the web browser DOES trigger the Spring Boot `authserver` app to create logs documenting the request, giving the following xml in the browser:

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AuthserverApplication.java, you overrided Spring security with `.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`. 
That means every request requires the user to be authenticate.

Try to change the permission in Spring Security on GET /user to grant access to unauthenticated users (if your nodeJs server doesn't send Auth token/header/cookie when calling your spring service)

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
             .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Comment: That did not resolve the problem.  The immediate issue was that the Node.js route had to be changed from `/user/**` to become `/user**` instead.  That got the call to be made to the Spring backend, but the result is an unauthorized error, whether or not I add your code.

Comment: You request may be also intercepted by the CSRF filter which ils ON by default. Try to add http.csrf().disable() I hope it will solve your problem.